# Is there an api for the admin websocket server in dart's pub serve?

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I have noticed that when I do a `pub serve --mode=debug` I get 2 servers one on port 8080 and the other 'admin' server on 8079.  8079 seems to be a websocket server judging by the message I get when I navigate to it.
So the question is what does it do?  Can I milk it for useful debugging information, or is it just for controlling the monkeys inside the machine? 
Are there any docs on this?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen any detailed information beside this traking bug https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=16954

Accessing it with the browser just returns

> Currently this server only accepts Web Socket connections.